# first and second derivative of a function similar to the Gaussian PDF

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am trying to understand the qualitative behavior in the region $x \in \left(\infty, 0
\right]$.

For $x \in \left(-\infty, -1 \right)$:

$\frac{df}{dx} < 0$ and $\frac{df^{2}}{dx^{2}} < 0$.

At $x = -1$:
$\frac{df}{dx} = 0$. $\frac{df^{2}}{dx^{2}} = 0. $

How do I think about the sudden transition to $\frac{df}{dx} <0$ to $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$?

Comment: I would say that there is no "sudden" transition (which, for the record, wouldn't be "sudden" anyways): the best guess is that $f''(-1)>0$ and that there is an inflection point somewhere in $(-2,-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "U-turn" at $x=-1$. Whenever you have that kind of shape, the slope (i.e. derivative) is transitioning from negative to positive, which means it has to pass through 0. So you have $\frac{df}{dx}<0$ for $x<-1$, $\frac{df}{dx}>0$ for $x>-1$, and $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ for $x=-1$. Nothing sudden about the transition.

Of course, this type of reasoning holds up only for smooth (continuous, differentiable) functions. Visually, the function you have posted here looks smooth.